# How to define when show or not a loading screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So, I have this app that uses this code to show and hide a loading screen upon all the screen content while it loads some ajax request.

```
app.config( function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider )
{
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function( $rootScope )
    {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show')
                return config
            },
            response: function(response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide')
                return response
            }
        }
    });
})
.run(function( $state, $rootScope, $ionicLoading, $storage )
{
    $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function() 
    {
        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading'});
    });

    $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function() 
    {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
});
```

When I want to loading something I use:

```
$http.post( "http://myexample.com.br/json-data", {param1:"1"} ).then(function(result){});
```

The problem is that I want, in some situations, to load something in background and not show a loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have set it up using the interceptors, those loading events will be raised on every `$http` call. I'd recommend removing the event listeners from the `$rootScope` and only apply them on individual controller scopes that you do want the loading screen to show.

Comment: I will probably end up with this if anything else don't come up. The thing is, I need this loading feature in all situations, except by one. =\

Answer (score 0):

I put `$ionicLoading.hide();` just after the `$http.post`. Not the best, but solve.

```
$http.post( "http://myexample.com.br/json-data", {param1:"1"}).then(function(result)
{

});

$ionicLoading.hide();
```